# Method crashes every time I put the first integer into array. Bad operation?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, multidimensional-array

I have a method which fills the array with integers:

```
void  fill(int* a[], int dim1, int dim2)
{
int intinArray = 0;
for(int i=0;i<dim1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<dim2;j++)
    {
    cin >> intinArray;
    a[i][j] = intinArray;
    }
  }
}
```

If I declare array in method `main()` like this:

```
int** tab;
fill(tab,3,3);
```

It crashes when I put the first integer in `cin`. Why? If there's a problem with this line:

```
a[i][j] = intinArray;
```

how should I change it?

Comment: All of your pointers that you've shown are uninitialized. To use a pointer, it must point somewhere valid first. So of course it crashes.

Comment: It looks like you have misplaced your C++ book.

Comment: You should know to use new so we knew to say no.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental thing wrong with your code is that you declared pointers, but nowhere do you initialize the pointers to point somewhere.  You treat the pointer as if it is a regular old 2 dimensional array of integer.  So if it's as easy as that, why use pointers?

Given that this is a fundamental in pointer usage and you plainly aren't doing that, the solution is to review working code that uses pointer.

```
int main()
{
  int *p;  // uninitialized -- points to who-knows-where
  *p = 10;  // this is undefined behavior and may crash
}
```

Take that code and understand why it also may crash. That pointer points to "we don't know", and then you're assigning 10 to a location that is unknown to you, me, and everyone else reading this answer.  See the problem?  To fix it, you have to initialize the pointer to point somewhere valid, *then* you can dereference it and assign to it without error.

```
int main()
{
  int *p;  // uninitialized -- points to who-knows-where
  int x = 20;
  p = &x;  // this is now ok, since p points to x
  *p = 20;  // now x changes to 20
}
```

Comment: But what if we have multi-dimensional array? Should I initialize pointer to the place of array?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this code

```
int** tab; // <- this one
fill(tab,3,3);
```

You declared a pointer, and are using it under the assumption that it is pointing to allocated memory. (I guess a source of confusion is that with C++ objects this isn't really the case)

A pointer is a pointer - it points to a location in memory. There's no guarantee that the value it points to is valid unless you explicitly make sure it is yourself.
Read PaulMcKenzie's answer for more about pointers.

Try

```
int tab[x][y] = {{0}}; 
fill(tab,3,3);
```

where x and y define your 2D array's width and height. You're going to have to handle bounds checking for your application.
Note that changing {{0}} to a non zero number will not initialize everything to that number.